# Git Unable to Commit

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am getting the following issue when attempting to commit on github desktop to github:

```
error: cannot spawn null: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Originally I was getting just a `fatal` error based on the cannot spawn null, but then I ran

```
git config --global commit.gpgsign tru
```

to get the current error.

I tried deleting and then re-cloning the repo and even individually deleting every file in the repo that I can without making github desktop no longer register the directory as a repo, to no avail. I have no idea how to resolve this at this point or what would even be causing the issue. Ideas?

Note: the issue is located to this single repo, all my other repos are working fine.

Edit:

Results of:

```
git config --local -l
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
submodule.active=.
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/***{this information is correct}***.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
commit.gpgsign=true
```

Comment: Please post the output of `git config --local -l`. Something is odd in your config and that would be the first place I'd look. Do be sure to block out any usernames or passwords that show up.

Comment: Added results of above requested code.